# Filter Options in React

Tags: ecmascript-6, react.js, redux

I have several products. A product can have 1 or more images. In each image, we have content slot. I don't want duplication per content slot in a product.

My code works fine. I'm just wondering what will be a better way to do this or improvement on my code?

Codesandbox is here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-added-array-of-object-inside-another-aray-in-react-forked-uxqce?file=/src/components/MediaCard/index.js)

```
    <Autocomplete
      fullWidth
      size="small"
      options={
        Boolean(product.slot) && product.slot.length > 0
          ? contentSlots.filter(
              (slot) =>
                !product.slot.find((data) => data.value.id === slot.id)
            )
          : contentSlots
      }
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Content Slots"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ""}
      disableClearable={true}
      onChange={(_, value) => onChangeContentSlot(value, product)}
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering of options logic can be simplified a bit. Instead of first checking that the product slot array exists and has a truthy length, just allow the array's `.find` method to handle empty arrays, using Optional Chaining to access this deeply into the `product` object. You can also merge the two logic branches by returning `true` when the conditions are not met and the currently iterated element should ***not*** be filtered out, which happens any time the optional chaining hits a null or undefined property ***or*** there are no matches found.

```
options={contentSlots.filter(
  (slot) => !product?.slot?.find((data) => data.value.id === slot.id)
)}
```

Comment: How about on the reducer? appConstants.CHANGE_CONTENT_SLOTS. Was it structured and coded correctly? or there is a better way?

Comment: @Joseph Oh, sorry, I thought you were only asking about the filtering of options. Yeah, the `CHANGE_CONTENT_SLOTS` reducer case looks good to me.